# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method resultSet::free()

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to get a function working on an old php based application, [autonomous lan party](http://www.nerdclub.net/alp/). It is based on php4 but it does work with what I want it to do on a php5 server (it is also only used in an intranet environment). I'm adding an accounting add-on [from here](http://www.morb.ath.cx/alp/). I can understand php, but still somewhat rusty.

Below is a small sample of code I'm stuck with...

```
<FORM ACTION="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" METHOD="post" NAME="accounting" ID="accounting">
<strong>user: </strong><br>
    <SELECT NAME="userid[]" SIZE="5" class="formcolors" TABINDEX="1" MULTIPLE>
<?php
            $data = $dbc->query('SELECT username,userid FROM users ORDER BY username');
            while ( $row = $data->fetchRow()) {
              $option = '
                    <OPTION VALUE="%s" class="formcolors">%s</OPTION>';
              printf($option, $row['userid'], $row['username']);
        }
        $data->free();
        unset($option, $data);
?>
</SELECT>
```

The problem is once it reaches te `$data->free();` line, the script stops executing and supplies the error mentioned in the topic. If I comment it out (twice, there is a similar line) the script runs but once i submit the data I get another error in the logfile...

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I believe that error is because I've commented out `$data->free();` so it's not able to get the correct result.

I've pasted the full code from the file at pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/aVyyLTU4) (didnt want to fill this page up with all the other code).

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated. Everything else on the application works as expected.

Comment: Is `$data` *really* a class instance? If so, you might want to supply the code for that class. Also, where from is the `mysql_escape_string()` called from?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `$data` is a mysql result.

To free the result from memory, try using [`mysqli_free_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) instead.

```
$data = $dbc->query('SELECT username,userid FROM users ORDER BY username');
while ( $row = $data->fetchRow()) {
    $option = '
          <OPTION VALUE="%s" class="formcolors">%s</OPTION>';
          printf($option, $row['userid'], $row['username']);
}
mysqli_free_result($data->free());
unset($option, $data);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion. Correct, `$data` is a mysql result. I've tried the `mysql_free_result()` as suggested but have run into the same issue. I has given me a bit more to go on though, thankyou.

Comment: You get an error stating it can't find the function, or you get the `mysql_escape_string()` error?

Comment: Sorry, I get the original error of 'Call to undefined method resultset::free()'